# Is it possible to have a single data Entity using SwiftData? (non-array, like persistent app settings)

Tags: swiftui, persistence, swift-data

I would like to have a settings entity with SwiftData. I would like it to store my active entity that the user was working with when they last used the app, plus a few other settings that I would like to persist between uses.

Unfortunately if I use `@Query var setting: Setting`, it doesn't work because it requires an array.  But if I use it as an array with the intention to only use the first index `@Query var setting: [Setting]` I have issues, as I will not be able to use setting as an `ObservableObject` throughout my app (that I know).

I've tried `@Binding`, but I'm afraid I just dont know enough about SwiftData, and I would appreciate any help.

I'm also pretty sure that if I query or bind the settings without attaching it to the modelContainer it isn't going to work anyways.

Surely there is an easier way to have my settings persist.

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct DataTestApp: App {
    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        let schema = Schema([
            Item.self,
            Setting.self,
        ])
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)

        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()
    
    @Binding var settings: Setting

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()

        }
        .modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
        .environmentObject(settings)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why SwiftData? Why is `AppStorage` unsuitable?